# Subscribe on a channel only for my orders using laravel echo

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, echo, subscribe

Recently i'm starting to use Laravel Echo, now a I have a doubt. Suppose that I'm develop a web store. I as a user for my web store have a list of my orders in different states (pending, approved, failed, shipping, etc). I want to update the status in realtime using Laravel Echo.

How can I subscribe only for events on my orders and not for all orders of the web store?.

```
Echo.channel('orders') //only my orders
.listen('OrderStatus', (e) => {
    console.log(e.order.status);
});
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on a private channel.

```
Echo.private('orders.' + user.id) //only your orders
.listen('OrderStatus', (e) => {
    console.log(e.order.status);
});
```

assuming you have some user in your javascript.

Now you will need to set up a channel route in your routes/channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('orders.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return $user->id === $userId;
});
```

Now a user can only listen to their own orders channel. A great reference for Laravel Echo is the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels).